# Android: How do I use the volume buttons to initialize an app?

Tags: android

I'm like working on an app that will call home when I press down the volume.

I have a working Dial / Call method. Now I need help figuring out how to get it all encapsulated in a method that will activate when the volume key down is pressed and held.

Any advice would help immensely.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896746/android-is-there-a-broadcast-action-for-volume-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`onKeyLongPress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyLongPress%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method to capture this event, something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
    {
        //Your Code here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

This only captures the Volum down event, and passes everything else on back to it's normal implentation.

Comment: I am just having a little bit of an issue with the bottom line of the code: return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event); that whole line of code is highlighted in red for some reason.

Comment: The problems tab should tell you what it is. If you can post that here I can help you with it.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type  
/WEBBSG4.0/res/layout line 11 Android Lint Problem
KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a variable   DHD.java /WEBBSG4.0/src/webb/four/zero line 21 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "event", delete this token DHD.java /WEBBSG4.0/src/webb/four/zero line 21 Java Problem

Comment: Have you imported android.view.KeyEvent?

Comment: I have, I just double checked to be sure.

Comment: Is your second parameter called event?

Comment: Yes it is, is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: Open a new question for this. I can't say more without seeing the code you're using.